# Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource gives wrong entity's property value during Updating or Deleting

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-4.5, entitydatasource

I am using the `Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource` like this:

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" DataSourceID="eds" ID="gv" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="#" ReadOnly="true" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Code" HeaderText="Code" ReadOnly="true" />
    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowEditButton="true" ShowDeleteButton="true" />
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<ef:EntityDataSource runat="server" ID="eds" ConnectionString="name=Entities" 
                     EnableDelete="true" EnableInsert="True" EnableUpdate="True"
                     EntitySetName="awCategoryGroups" DefaultContainerName="Entities" EnableFlattening="False"
                     Where="it.isValid=true"  OrderBy="it.Name asc" OnDeleting="eds_Deleting">
</ef:EntityDataSource>
```

It creates a table with records (entities) of type `awCategoryGroup`. The problem is, when I want to delete the record using the delete button from `GridView CommandField` whic calls the `eds_Deleting` method.

C#:

```
protected void eds_Deleting(object sender, Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource.EntityDataSourceChangingEventArgs e)
{
    awCategoryGroup cg = (awCategoryGroup)e.Entity;
    cg.isValid = false;
    e.Context.SaveChanges();
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

The database looks like this when selecting data for `GridView`.

DB:

```
ID  Name    Code    isValid
==========================================
19  Roles   UserRole    True
20  Actions ActionType  True
```

**The goal** should be to set `isValid` column to `False`. But when `eds_Deleting` method is called, the `(awCategoryGroup)e.Entity` contains corresponding values of its properties except the `bool` (in DB as `bit`) valued property `isValid`. **It should be `True`, but it is `False` already before I set it.** 
So no save occures when calling `e.Context.SaveChanges();`, because the properties are not modified.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong? This philosophy worked fine on EF4, but after migrating to EF6, there is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the **`isValid` must be as one of the visible columns** in the `GridView`.

So `eds_Deleting` exactly do not work with the entity from database but only with its part used in `GridView`. Values not used in `GridView` are of default value (usually `null` or `false`).

So this is inter alia the difference between `EF5 EntityDataSource` and `EF6 EntityDataSource`. **EF5 version worked with the fully loaded object, but EF6 do not.**